# JavaFX alert automatically closing

Tags: javafx, javafx-8

I have an fxml application in which the fxml has a cancel button defined and an onAction handler.

```
@FXML
protected void onCancel(ActionEvent event) {

    event.consume();
    Alert alert = new Alert(AlertType.CONFIRMATION);
    alert.setTitle("Cancel wizard");
    alert.setHeaderText("Are you sure you wish to cancel this wizard ?");
    alert.setContentText("Choose your option.");

    ButtonType buttonTypeYes = new ButtonType("Yes", ButtonData.YES);
    ButtonType buttonTypeNo = new ButtonType("No", ButtonData.NO);

    alert.getButtonTypes().setAll(buttonTypeYes, buttonTypeNo);

    Optional<ButtonType> result = alert.showAndWait();
    if (result.get() == buttonTypeYes) {
        getSkinnable().cancel();
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that when the esc key is pressed on the main screen the alert box just flashes up and disapears again, it would appear that the esc key event is still propogating around, because if I remove ButtonData.NO from the alert cancel buton the alert box displays as expected.

Is there a way to clear any keyboard events before displaying the alert box, or any other ideas on how I may achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible that you may have to consume the keyboard event on the main screen, if that Escape key event is propagating to the Alert popup. So, handle the key press event explicitly in the main screen and ensure that it is consumed to prevent it bubbling forward. Although, I would not recommend usage of the Escape key for anything other than cancellation. I'd also avoid consuming the event in this handler, unless it has truly been handled.

Comment: To add to what I stated above, I tried running a test using most of the code you gave above, with the exception of the "getSkinnable" call and it worked fine for me, without the escape key difficulties, simply by using a button press event to bring up the Alert box.

Comment: Yes I had the same result, when the cancel button was not was not defined as a "Cancel button" in the fxml. however as you pointed the esc key is useful for cancellation, but instead of just discarding any changes the user may have made, I am prompting with a cancellation alert box. I suspect I will have to remove the ButtonData.NO from the alert box, or try and consume the key event in the main screen, any suggestions on how to achieve this ?

Comment: Ah, right. I had misunderstood the nature of your cancel button above. Didn't realize that it was a default cancel button. Let me try something and I'll get back to you.

Comment: Okay, the only way I've managed to get it working for me, is to change the ButtonData from NO to OTHER. That's a reasonable solution in this scenario to be honest.

Comment: Only other way of doing it, that I can think of offhand, would be to subclass Alert and have a local boolean that you set to true when you wish to close the Alert (default to false initially). Then handle the onCloseRequest event and only allow the Alert to close if your boolean value is set to true. First time in, you can simply consume the close request event, then set it to true. Next time in, the boolean value will be true, ready for appropriate closure of the Alert. Make sense?

Comment: This guy had something similar... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35411021/prevent-dialog-from-closing-when-escape-key-is-pressed-in-javafx

Comment: Yes, makes sense. I didnt think there would be a simple answer, but your suggestion, seems about the cleanest way of doing it. Many thanks.

Comment: I would go with the ButtonData.OTHER approach myself. Seems cleanest and pragmatic rather than trying to reinvent how Java is dealing with automatic cancellations through complex event handling and consumption. Glad i was able to assist :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try displaying the alert inside `Platform.runLater`, and by that time the event will have finished propagating.

```
Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
    @Override public void run() {
        // alert code here
    }
});
```

Comment: I have tried using the platform.runlater with the same results